# Sort nested array by value?

Tags: arrays, underscore.js

I have a nested array like the following:

```
data = [
[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1), 1],
[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 5), 22],
[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 2), 2],
[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 11), 33]
]
```

I am using underscore and I am trying to figure out a way to sort it by the `Date.UTC` so the array shows dates by first to last or lowest to highest ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) with a function to pick off the first elements of the inner arrays:

> **sortBy** `_.sortBy(list, iterator, [context])`
>
> Returns a sorted copy of **list**, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value through **iterator**. Iterator may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. `length`).

So perhaps this:

```
_(data).sortBy(function(a) {
    return a[0];
});
```

Since `Data.UTC` gives you a number, you can throw in a negation to sort in the opposite direction:

```
_(data).sortBy(function(a) {
    return -a[0];
});
```

You could also do this:

```
_(data).sortBy('0')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mLDzH/