# Underscore JS - Sorting an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, functional-programming, underscore.js

I have an array made up of 80 individual objects. Within those individual objects I have a key: value pair. The key is `"number"` and values go from `"0001"` to `"0080"`.

So the structure would be something like

```
 myArray = [{number: "0001"}, {number: "0002"}, {number: "0003"} ]
```

and so on...

I'm using Underscore, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to order the individual objects so they're sorted 1,2,3,5. The values that are number are also strings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Can you show us what kind of objects you really have in JSON?

Comment: Look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334015/sort-nested-array-by-value

Comment: Looks like that key is useless and you should just go for `_.pluck(…, "number")` before sorting.

Answer (score 5):

Use [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function:

```js
var myArray = [{number: "0003"}, {number: "0001"},{number: "0002"} ];
var result = _.sortBy(myArray, "number");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

results in:

`[{number: "0001"}, {number: "0002"},{number: "0003"} ]`